# Почему не грузится картинка?

Tags: yii2

пытаюсь организовать загрузку вот модель

```
class ImageUpload extends Model
{
    public $imageFiles;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }
    public function upload(){
        $uploadPath=\Yii::getAlias('@app').'/web/image/post/'.date('Y').'/'.date('m');
        BaseFileHelper::createDirectory($uploadPath);
        if ($this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $imageFile=$uploadPath . '/' . $file->baseName.'.'.$file->extension;
                $file->saveAs($imageFile);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return var_dump($this->getErrors());
    }
}
```

вот контролер

```
class PostController extends Controller
{    
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Post();
        $imageUpload= new ImageUpload();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $imageUpload->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($imageUpload, 'imageFiles');
            $image=$imageUpload->upload();
            $saves=$model->saves($image,$model);
            if($saves){
                return $this->render('create',[
                    'model' => $model,
                    'imageUpload'=>$imageUpload
                ]);
            }
            return var_dump($image);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'imageUpload'=>$imageUpload
            ]);
        }
    }
```

вот вид

```
<div class="post-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'alias')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
    ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($imageUpload, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'preview')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
    ]) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

получаю ошибку `please upload file` в дебаге
`ImageUpload` пустой а `$_FILE` полный почему не подскажите ? И что делать?

Comment: Я так понимаю это стандартная ошибка для rules с типом file. Убедитесь, что файл в $_FILES приходит с указанным ключом imageFiles

Comment: @Skywave приходил там просто мне изменили задачу с мульти загрузки на загрузку одного файла.